# Animation Nodes, how to add additional outputs? Missing outputs

Tags: animation-nodes

I am following some basic tutorials on animation nodes with latest Blender 2.81.

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3N8H8X-GJk)

He is using older version of blender,
but right at the beginning he adds a Grid Mesh node with a very different output than what I find in mine.

[image]

For example, the same node "Grid Mesh" only has one output "Mesh" in my latest version, while in tutorial he has 3: Vertices, Edge Indices, Polygon Indices.

I am wondering if there is a way to add additional, missing, outputs in Grid Mesh node, or if there has been some change I am not aware about?1

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Mesh Info' node (Add -> Mesh -> Mesh info).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot add additional inputs or outputs in any node (e.g., Grid Mesh in your case). However, there is a **[Group-Node](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/group.html)** in **Subprogrames** category in Animation Nodes:
[image]

which allows creating any kind of inputs and/or outputs and arrange them as you like. You can also combine multiple nodes similar to the shader group-node. Here, I have made a simple example:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful for me to dig deeper. Recently, seeing all the insane #nodevember,  I was wondering how do they dig so deep and dynamic with just the nodes.

Comment: Does working like that expands into any node system? I did notice Shader editor has script node, but nothing like invoke subprogram.

Comment: Animation Nodes also has a Script Node in Subprogrames category. Sorry, "Does working like that expands into any node system?" do you want to know about the general workflow or something else?

Comment: yes please, i want to understand how these node systems are unified through general workflow. For example what’s the equivalent of invoke subprogram in shaders nodes ?

Comment: Do you mean Invoke Subprogram of the Animation Nodes in Shader Nodes or Invoke Subprogram of the Shader Nodes?

Comment: the latter one, Invoke Subprogram of the Shader Nodes.

Comment: There is no Invoke Subprogram of the Shader Nodes. However, there is OSL Programming Nodes addon: https://blendermarket.com/products/osl-programming-nodes to create custom shaders with nodes.